# PHP memcached session not working

Tags: php, session, apache2, memcached

I started to use memcached for storing session files, but Session  doesn't work and apache sends response too slow. How can I solve the problem?

Modifications in php.in are:

```
;session.save_handler = files
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&amp;weight=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_interval=15"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem, Solution is connection url without `tcp://`
,so `session.save_path` should be

```
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&amp;weight=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_interval=15"
```

Answer (score 0):

read this page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php

you should modify php.ini like that

```
session.save_handler = memcached
```

Change  memcached  to  memcache

Maybe Helpful for you

Else

That Check For Server Permissions And Check For Charset of Your PHP script And

Put this code:

in being:

```
<?php
ob_start ();
?>
```

at the end:

```
<?php
ob_flush ();
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work that change memcached to memcache because it gives error "PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'memcache'" when I change it

Comment: I'm Edit This Answer...
read this Maybe Helpful for you
I'm Sorry