# PHP Warning: session_ start(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, apache, session

We have one Amazon linux server which was never been used from last 3-4 months and when we start it to use, login module written in PHP has been completely broken. When I checked the standard httpd logs /var/log/httpd/error_log, it says:

> PHP Warning: session_start(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/sites/siteAdmin/authenticate.php on line 1

I have been referred to so many questions(on stackoverflow), articles and blogs regarding this, but none of them worked for me. Please help.

Authenticate.php

```
session_start();
global $dbname,$dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$_SERVER;
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/_db_config.php");
$db = mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpasswd);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
$msg = "";
$userName=$_REQUEST["userName"];
$password=$_REQUEST["password"];
$sql_result2 = mysql_query("select * from TBL where user = '$userName' and pass = '$password'", $db);
$rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);
if(count($rs2)>0){
 $adminId=$rs2[0];
 $_SESSION["adminId"] = $adminId;
 $_SESSION["loggedInFlag"] = 1;
 header("Location:main.php");
 exit();
}
else{
 header("Location:URL");
 exit();
}
```

session.* from phpinfo()

```
Directive                          Local Value  Master Value
session.auto_start                 Off          Off
session.bug_compat_42              Off          Off
session.bug_compat_warn            On           On
session.cache_expire               180          180
session.cache_limiter              nocache      nocache
session.cookie_domain              .URL         .URL
session.cookie_httponly            Off          Off
session.cookie_lifetime            0            0
session.cookie_path                /            /
session.cookie_secure              Off          Off
session.entropy_file               no value     no value
session.entropy_length             0            0
session.gc_divisor                 1000         1000
session.gc_maxlifetime             28800        28800
session.gc_probability             1            1
session.hash_bits_per_character    5            5
session.hash_function              0            0
session.name                       PHPSESSID    PHPSESSID
session.referer_check              no value     no value
session.save_handler               Memcache     Memcache
session.save_path                  tcp://URL:11111?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15
session.serialize_handler          php          php
session.use_cookies                On           On
session.use_only_cookies           On           On
session.use_trans_sid              0            0
```

Comment: I just tried to write few lines of code {session_start();
echo session_id();}, but its not working. It doesn't show anything

Comment: I meant: `I have been referred to so many questions(on stackoverflow), articles and blogs regarding this, none of them worked for me`, it could have been useful to know what you tried to solve your problem and why it didn't work. :)

Comment: At once, I found that DNS may have some problem, so I flushed the DNS. Then I tried to reset my session_path. Then I upgraded PHP from 5.3.1 to 5.3.6, but that didn't work too.

Comment: Have you put `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the top of your script, before trying your session stuff?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show anything. And in logs, it says the same thing.

Comment: would you mind to share the code of this file (authenticate.php) and is it included in other files?

Comment: What is in authenticate.php at line 1? Would you also share your `session.*` from `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Can you resolve the server's hostname from itself ? Any "funky" entries given by its DNS server or in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: @Oras - I have added authenticate.php in question itself.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I have added session.* in question itself.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus Yes I can ping this machine and there are no funky entries given in hosts file. It only contains `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: Did you edit out the `session.save_path` setting to be `tcp://URL:11111?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15
` or is that the original value? PHP can't resolve the hostname of your memcache server to start the session.

Comment: @madebydavid yes I have intentionally changed it to URL instead of actual ec2 domain name. It was something like tcp://ec2-IP-AD-DR-ESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11111?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15

Comment: Can you ping the memcache server host from the command line of the linux box running PHP? Perhaps the hostname is incorrect, or that instance is no longer running. If it is running and you know the IP, try adding an entry to /etc/hosts for it and then restarting apache.

Comment: By the way your code is higly insecure and shows a perfect path for SQL injections.

Comment: According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215323/php-memcached-session-not-working , only need to remove `tcp://`

Comment: @madebydavid your answer helped me in getting the issue. It was the memcache URL which was creating a problem. Please answer this question with the same text and I will give the bounty amount to you.

Comment: @regilero This is the code done by someone else. I have been moved here to fix all such things. Thanks for pointing that out. I really appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message suggests that PHP can't resolve the hostname of your memcache server to start the session.

You can see the URL for the memcache server in the `session.save_path` setting.

Can you ping the memcache server host from the command line of the linux box running PHP?

Perhaps the hostname is incorrect, or that instance is no longer running.

If it is running and you know the IP, try adding an entry to /etc/hosts for it and then restarting Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Your session save path is wrong, you have it configured as `tcp://URL:` whereas that should clearly be a real URL or IP address.

If you are not using memcache then I would suggest you simply comment out or remove the `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path` settings so that PHP uses its standard defaults for session storage which should then work fine.

Comment: It didn't work in my case. I just made sure the URL is working and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you get `php_network_getaddresses` it means that PHP failed to resolve an hostname and it could be fired when you connect to an external (even local) service by name.

First your server will look into your `/etc/hosts` file to translate the hostname into an IP address and if it fails it will try to resolve it on a DNS (what will only work if the name is "public").

To bypass this problem, add a new entry on your `/etc/hosts` file like the one below

```
127.0.0.1    URL
```

where `URL` is in your `session.save_path` and I am assuming that it points to the same server.